# .NET CORE 6 Returns 503 Error after a couple of requests

Tags: c#, iis, build, asp.net-core-webapi, publish

I published a NET CORE 6 WEB API on my IIS 10.0 web server

The application read and write(using get/post) data from a SQL Server 2017 database hosted on another machine on the same virtual network of the web server.
Everything works fine but after a couple of requests it stop working and send Http Error 503 Service Unavailable and I have to restart it every time from the application pool.
I enabled tracing on the event log, but I don't receive any message explaining this, tried log code but dont receive anything too.
No crashes when debugging in VS via console app. It also crashes if the requests are made from postman(usually I do it from my site)

I tried with Throttle configuration, CORS and I don't find many people who have the same problem with the particularity that it works at first and after a couple of requests (50? 100? The number varies) does not work anymore

EDIT: fixed, on webconfig i changed value of hostingModel from 'inprocess' to 'outofprocess'. I hope it helps you.

Comment: are there no exception messages *anywhere*? you mention app-pool: is there a Windows event-log item? it takes quite a lot to kill the process...

Comment: 0 exception messages, in log of iis or code(shows successful runs returning 200 and stops logging.)

Comment: Emmm, no exception messages. May you can refer to the  IIS Support Blog: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/http-response-503-service-unavailable-from-iis-one-common/ba-p/1720007#:~:text=The%20503%20response%20from%20the,application%20pool%20is%20turned%20off.

Comment: Even a stack overflow should leave a trace! You're managing to break this *real* hard. Impossible to say more without code.

Comment: I have the same exact issue as you.  One thing I noticed is that I can make a couple high memory calls, once it hits the end of the second call it does a garbage collection and boom, everything stops no error messages, just returns 503. Did you ever get this one solved?

Comment: @Behr solved, check the last edit, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation as you. The issue I had was this was being called to get configuration from the appsettings.json:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApiSettingsConfig");
```

Note, this was not in the startup.cs - this was in a controller.

The thing was, I could call that multiple times and it runs fine. After the system does garbage collection, it starts returning 503 and I'd have to restart the application.

The solution was to have a static Configuration setup in the Startup.cs that could be accessed from anywhere, then call that static configuration whenever you need to get values out of the appsettings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was calling `CreateBuilder` more than once.

Removing the extra call per [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/asp-net-core-503-server-has-been-shutdown/ba-p/3830338) seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: Please add some more explanation as opposed to only linking to a tutorial.

Comment: J Swarts, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)